# Using CDC tables to create DB state as on a previous date

Tags: sql-server-2008, relational-database, cdc

I have a complex data model consisting of 100s of tables. I have CDC enabled for all tables and have that data in corresod nponding CDC tables. I need a generic mechanism whereby given a arbitrary SELECT query I am able to return results corresponding to a point of time in the past.

I did not find any online recipes or blogs about this. I have managed to realize on my own so far that in order to convert a normal SELECT query into its CDC-aware equivalent, it is important to consider cardinality of JOINs and have some logic around choosing transactions that matter. But it seems too complex and error-prone to write an equivalent query by hand on a per-query basis. Is there a tool out there which does that? or is this a market gap?

Comment: I think this would be very complex to work this out using CDC, if even possible. Do you not have full/log backups to restore to a point in time?

Comment: It sounds like you want something like Temporal Tables(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables) but at the database level. That's not a thing, but if you wanted to try creating every single table in your database as a Temporal table, and build a solution on that, it would probably be a better starting point than CDC.

Comment: Snodgrass's seminal work on time-oriented database applications is free from his web page: [Developing Time-Oriented Database Applications in SQL](https://www2.cs.arizona.edu/~rts/tdbbook.pdf). It's harder to do this right than you might think.

Comment: The typical way to achieve this is to pipe the CDC to a data warehouse, adding a timestamp and Insert/Delete/Update indicator to every row. (Also probably add structure to recreate history as at end of week and/or end of financial month: that goes to aggregates in your cubes.) If you haven't already designed the transactional database's schema to be temporal-aware, retrofitting some temporal structure is going to drive you mad (and your users). To answer your q: no there's no "market gap"; this is what data warehouses are good at and transactional databases/SQL are not.

Answer (score 0):

Change Data Capture  in general  would allow you to replicate the changes on the original database tables to  a new target table.

One approach is that you could use  LiveAudit or similar auditing functionality to  have a full audit trail of the changes on that Table. (Insert all changes to an Audit table for ongoing history).  You would still have to have some complex queries to  identify the  latest version of a Row based on Primary Key  up to the time in question.
(https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSTRGZ_11.4.0/com.ibm.cdcdoc.mcadminguide.doc/concepts/mappingliveaudit.html ) **IBM product, not MS SQL-CDC.

Temporal Tables may be a better approach, but it has its own complexities with design.

Both approaches could be limited by how much history you retain.
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-temporal-tables-retention-policy )